# Use Perl to manipulate file from within Octave

Tags: python, perl, file, octave, file-manipulation

I have a need to manipulate a file from within Octave in the middle of a routine. At the moment I end this routine by saving a file from Octave with

```
save data_for_training -ascii train_data
```

and then manually, and tediously, edit the saved file and then resume operations in a new and different Octave routine by first reading the edited file. Conceptually the file manipulations required are the reverse of those outlined in [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247499/use-python-to-manipulate-txt-file-presentation-of-key-value-grouping), namely a saved file that looks like this

```
a b c d e f ... z 0 0 0 0 1  
g h i j k l ... z 0 0 0 1 0
```

has to be manipulated to

```
a b c d e f ... z  
0 0 0 0 1  
g h i j k l ... z  
0 0 0 1 0
```

where the letters are actually numbers, but I have used letters for clarity. The line breaks will always be before the fifth to last number on each line i.e. the last 0 0 0 0 1 on each line will need to be moved below the line and all numbers on all lines are space separated.

I have tagged this question with the Perl and Python tags as there are [Perl and Python functions in Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Controlling-Subprocesses.html#index-perl-3253) and so I assume that I can easily achieve what I want by writing a scriptfile to do the above manipulations. If I am correct in this assumption can anyone give me a start/weblink for the Perl/Python scriptfiles - I have never used either before?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more on the conditions for your data manipulation. It's not like we can guess where you want line-breaks inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
while (<>) {
   my @f = split;
   print("@f[0..$#f-5]\n@f[-5..-1]\n");
}
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
while (<>) {
   s/\S\K\s+(?=\S+(?:\s+\S+){4}$)/\n/;
   print;
}
```

Usage:

```
perl script.pl file.in >file.out
```

or

```
script.pl file.in >file.out   # Requires: chmod u+x script.pl
```

or

```
perl -pale'$_="@F[0..$#F-5]\n@F[-5..-1]"' file.in >file.out
```

or

```
perl -pe's/\S\K\s+(?=\S+(?:\s+\S+){4}$)/\n/' file.in >file.out
```

Comment: You have spaces at the end of on of your lines. If that's truly the case with your actual data, you'll need to change `$` to `\s*\z`.

Answer (score 0):

```
open my $input,  '<', 'data_for_training';
open my $output, '>', 'data_for_training2';

while( <$input> ) {
    chomp;
    ( my $line  = $_ ) =~ s/((\s\d+){5})$//;
    ( my $line2 = $1 ) =~ s/^\s//;

    print $output "$line\n$line2\n";
}
close $input;
close $output;
```